# I am on Mac version 10.15.3 and facing the error [-bash: chsh: command not found] .before it was working properly.below is the terminal view

Tags: command-line, path, macos

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(base) Ashutoshs-MacBook-Air:~ ashutoshrudraksh$ 
(base) Ashutoshs-MacBook-Air:~ ashutoshrudraksh$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
-bash: chsh: command not found
(base) Ashutoshs-MacBook-Air:desktop ashutoshrudraksh$ python
-bash: python: command not found
(base) Ashutoshs-MacBook-Air:desktop ashutoshrudraksh$  sudo make install
-bash: sudo: command not found
(base) Ashutoshs-MacBook-Air:desktop ashutoshrudraksh$ echo $PATH
’/usr/local/bin:??
```

#### Summary

As you can see I have tried to run the command

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

but I got the error message

```
chsh:command not found
```

Also, any simple task I try to perform on the command line is no longer possible, although it did work before. Now I always get the error message

```
command not found
```

Is there any problem with the path or shell default? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have somehow managed to set your `PATH` to a strange value.

The default `PATH` on a macOS system:

```
$ getconf PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

`chsh` is located in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ command -v chsh
/usr/bin/chsh
```

You should revisit your shell's initialization files to see what you have done to mangle the value of `PATH`.

You should still be able to use `chsh`, but unless you correct your `PATH` variable's value, you will have to give the full path to the utility:

```
/usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Comment: please guide me with the above steps . are you willing me to run the commands on my mac as you shown above.

Comment: @iron_fist The first two commands that I show are just included to underline my text. The first one shows what the default value of `PATH` is and the second shows where `chsh` is located.  You should correct your shell's initialization files (where it sets `PATH`), because you have some code in there that sets an invalid value. The last command shows how you may use `chsh` without correcting that error.

Comment: can i run the last command of yours directly without changing the path

Comment: but i am getting the error [chsh: no changes made] inside the terminal

Comment: @iron_fist 1) Yes, if you give the full path to the command. 2) Then your login shell has already been changed to the shell you specified with `chsh`.